# How to create a Minecraft chunk in opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm learning OpenGL and I have tried to make a voxel game like Minecraft. In the beginning, everything was good. I created a CubeRenderer class to render a cube with its position. The below picture is what I have done.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjf80.jpg

And then I got a serious problem when I try to create a large terrain, I hit a slowing performance. It was very slow and fps just around 15fps, I thought. 
Next, I figured out Minecraft chunk and culling face algorithm can solve slowing performance by dividing the world map into small pieces like chunk and just rendering visible faces of a cube. So how to create a chunk in the right way and how the culling face algorithm is applied in Chunk?

So far, that is what I have tried
I read about Chunk in Minecraft at https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Chunk

I created a demo Chunk by this below code (it is not the completed code because I removed it out)

I created a CubeData that contains cube position and cube type.
And I call the GenerateTerrain function to make a simple chunk data (16x16x16) like below (CHUNK_SIZE is 16)

```cpp
for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {  
        for (int y = 0; y < CHUNK_SIZE; y++) {  
            for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
                CubeType cubeType = { GRASS_BLOCK }; 
                Location cubeLocation = { x, y, z };
                CubeData cubeData = { cubeLocation, cubeType };
                this->Cubes[x][y][z] = cubeData;
            }
        }
    }
```

After that, I had a boolean array which is called "mask" contains two values are 0 (not visible) or 1 (visible) and matches with their cube data. And then I call Render function of Chunk class to render a chunk. This code below like what I have done (but it is not complete code because I removed that code and replaced with new code)

```
for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {  
        for (int y = 0; y < CHUNK_SIZE; y++) {  
            for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
                for(int side = 0; side < 6;side++){
if(this->mask[x][y][z][side] == true) cubeRenderer.Render(cubeData[x][y][z]);
}
            }
        }
    }
```

But the result I got that everything still slow (but it is better than the first fps, from 15fps up to 25-30fps, maybe)

I guess it is not gpu problem, it is a cpu problem because there is too many loops in render call.

So I have kept research because I think my approach was wrong. There may have some right way to create a chunk, right?

So I found the solution that puts every visible verticle to one VBO. So I just have to call and bind VBO definitely one time.

So this below code show what I have tried

```cpp
cout << "Generating Terrain..." << endl;

    for (int side = 0; side < 6; side++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < CHUNK_SIZE; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < CHUNK_SIZE; y++) {
                for (int z = 0; z < CHUNK_SIZE; z++) {
                    if (this->isVisibleSide(x, y, z, side) == true) {
                        this->cubeRenderer.AddVerticleToVBO(this->getCubeSide(side), glm::vec3(x, y, z), this->getTexCoord(this->Cubes[x][y][z].cubeType, side));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    this->cubeRenderer.GenerateVBO();
```

And call render one time at all.

```
void CubeChunk::Update()
{
    this->cubeRenderer.Render(); // with VBO data have already init above
}
```

And I got this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDw0N.jpg

I think my way was wrong.

So what should I do to create a chunk? Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have read it when I begin to solve slowing performance. I got a basic idea behind that post and read a lot of posts that are related to it. But I cannot find the right way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for that. I also read it like the above answer that I said. The problem is I don't what I should do at the beginning. How about the input data ? How about the Chunk class should be ? Besides, the Javascript version may is a shorted version and it is very hard to follow. The java version may easier for me but like I have said before. Did those above things that I tried was wrong ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are so enthusiastically. To summarize what I got from you. I create a 3D array of voxels (contains its position and cube type), then with each voxel data, I decide which face of the cube should visible or not by meshing algorthimn and put those visible faces to VBO. In other words, I put every visible triangles to one VBO. And finally, I use that VBO and call OpenGL to render it out. If that is right, then I have tried that like above with culling meshing algorthimn and I got the above result.

Comment: You only have to find the visible (external) surfaces once (at creation)  and again when a block is placed or removed in the sub-chunk.  So the calculation you are doing every frame only needs to be done when the sub-chunk changes.

Comment: yeah, I have done that before. Like what I said, the problem is the loop. In Update function (when I want to render anything, I will put it in Update), I need to check which face is visible (by the mask array I have created before) and it leads to a lot of loops in Update. So I changed it. I put every visible verticle in VBO first (that I just find the visible once), and in Update, I call OpenGL to render everything. I can look the last picture I => something gone wrong.

Comment: Constructing the 3d model in a loop every frame will hurt performance. During intialization, construct the model and save as a list in memory, call the model in your renderer, you can use culling or octree algorithm to further improve performance if the game world is large.

Comment: see [How to best write a voxel engine in C with performance in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48092685/2521214) for some ideas